# Is it possible to check if a restricted file exists using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, permissions

For example, I am user abc and have a file in a directory which has a permission of 600 and gives below output:

```
ll /path/to/the/file
ls: cannot access /path/to/the/file: Permission denied
```

Is it possible using python script to check if this file exists?
Is it possible to give abc access to this file via sudoers file? If yes, what is the syntax to follow inside /etc/sudoers file for the user abc.?

Comment: Run the python script with `sudo` to see if it exists

Comment: It asks for sudo passwd.

Comment: Then enter the sudo password